# How do properties' datasources work?

Tags: vb.net, properties, datasource

I'm reviewing some code I have to modify, but there are some things that aren't that obvious to me.

There is a class, from which you call a property, and then a datasource and then even tables with a parameter, such as this:

```
MyClass.MyProperty.DataSource.Tables(0)
```

Now I know I can get whatever data MyProperty has easily, but I'm not really sure what the DataSource.Tables(0) part is attempting to do, it actually does get a series of values, I just don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

just hazarding a guess here:

```
Class SomeClass
    public Property MyProperty as SomeOtherClass
End Class

Class SomeOtherClass
    Public Property DataSource as DataSet
End Class

Dim MyClass as SomeClass
```

MyClass is the base class instance

MyClass.MyProperty calls the SomeOtherClass instance.

MyClass.MyProperty.DataSource calls the DataSet in the SomeOtherClass instance

And MyClass.MyProperty.DataSource.Tables(0) calls for the first DataTable in the DataSet contained in the SomeOtherClass instance